# Enabling TLS 1.0 on Dokku

Tags: docker, nginx, dokku

I'm running a rest api on Dokku platform. Recently I discovered that Android <5 doesn't support tls 1.1 and 1.2, so I was wondering if I could enable 1.0 on my host (default `cert` enabled only 1.2).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to get a certificate from an authority that supports lower than TLS 1.2, though I believe that is a requirement for GDPR.